# Search Solr ShingleFilterFactory

Tags: search

I have a data collection on Solr and I need to make a search and look for all typed words.

For example, if a user introduces the text "House Tree Spain" Solr should look for "House Tree Spain", "House Tree", "House Spain", "Tree Spain" "House", "Tree", "Spain".

I'm using "solr.ShingleFilterFactory" but just when I analyze the query.

```
<fieldType name="generic" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>

   <!-- generic -->       
   <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />

   <!-- spanish -->
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" />

   <!-- english -->
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />
  </analyzer>

  <analyzer type="query">
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>

   <!-- generic -->       
   <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />

   <!-- spanish -->
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_es.txt" />

   <!-- english -->
   <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" />

   <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="10" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="true"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

How can I change my schema to get the results I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the Shingle filter to both the query and index analyzers. In the indexing phase, it creates the tokens "House Tree" and "Tree Spain", and puts them in the index.  In the query phase, it creates those tokens out of the query and searches for them in the index.  If either of those steps is omitted, then "House Tree" can never match, see?

PS.  shingle size of 10 is huge.  For this particular example, you only need 2.  Set it as low as you can, otherwise, your index size grows very large.